# AngularJS Bad resource name

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and I'm trying to use the resource 'datatables' used in the template, but I keep getting bad resource name. I'm completely lost at this point and any help would be welcome.

I copied from the template both controler and module:

```
datatable.controller.js
tables.module.js
```

the view:

```
table-datatable.pug
```

added to app.module.js:

```
'app.tables',
```

added the route to the view on routes.config.js:

```
.state('app.table-datatable', {
     url: '/table-datatable',
     title: 'Table Datatable',
     templateUrl: helper.basepath('table-datatable.html'),
     resolve: helper.resolveFor('datatables')
})
```

and after all that I get this message on browser's console:

```
Error: Route resolve: Bad resource name [datatables]
```

I copied everything from the template. While it's working on the template, I can't get it to work on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to inject the dependency on the lazyload.constants.js file.

The file stays as follows:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.lazyload')
    .constant('APP_REQUIRES', {
      // jQuery based and standalone scripts
      scripts: {
        ...
      },
      // Angular based script (use the right module name)
      modules: [
        ...
          {name: 'datatables',
           files: [
                    'vendor/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css',
                    'vendor/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
                    'vendor/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js',
                    'vendor/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap.js',
                    'vendor/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js',
                    'vendor/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js',
                    'vendor/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js',
                    'vendor/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.js',
                    'vendor/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.js',
                    'vendor/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.js'
                  ],
                  serie: true},
         ]
    });

})();
```

After that I had to make sure the files were indeed in vendor's folder and everything is working now.